# How to fetch attribute value under elements/elements in xml using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<test-case name="SuccessfulOneTimePayment" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="211.262" asserts="9">
  <categories>
    <category name="Regression" />
  </categories>
  <properties>
    <property name="TestcaseId" value="70592" />
  </properties>
</test-case>
```

Can anyone help me to fetch TestcaseId value=70592 from this xml?

```
  var testcaseid = xml.Root.Descendants("test-case").Elements("categories").Elements("properties")

 .Where(s => s.Attribute("name") != null)
 .ToList();
```

I tried the above code which is not helping me.

Comment: Your query suggests that properties is a child of categories while it is not. Try `xml.Root.Descendants("test-case").Elements("properties")`.

Comment: Wouldn't XPath serve this well? Why LINQ?

Comment: @Shahkalpesh Take a look at Cuong Le's Answer below and you find how intuitive and nice is Linq on many sources from Databse to XML. Who really wants to learn one another language to work with XML?

Comment: @Alireza: Well, XPath has been the way to query xml (before LINQ). Unless there is a reason (such as joining XML with data coming from DB), I dont know why one would use LINQ for a trivial scenario. If the OP is familiar with LINQ, he/she should go for it.

Comment: @shahkalpesh Comparing Linq2XML with XPath is like comparing EntityFramework and Linq2Sql with naitive SQL.

Comment: @Alireza: Not in this case. Your comparison is not favorable. Your suggestion is to use entity framework and linq2sql for everything db, which I dont think is meaningful. As I said before, I am not against using LINQ. It depends on the problem at hand. Here is the xpath syntax `string(/test-case/properties/property[@name='TestcaseId']/@value)`. This assumes that it will always return 1 node. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument.Load(xml)
     .Descendants("property")
     .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "TestcaseId")
     .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("value"))
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What if there's extra descendants with a name of `property` and a value?

Comment: @It'sNotALie: Could you please elaborate more your question

Answer (score 0):

```
    XDocument newTrial = XDocument.Load(@"xxxxxxxxxxx\trial.xml");

     var value = from name in newTrial.Descendants("properties")
                    where name.Element("property").Attribute("name").Value != null && name.Element("property").Attribute("name").Value == "TestcaseId"  
                    select  name.Element("property").Attribute("value").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourXDocument
    .Root
    .Element("properties")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("property"))
    .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "TestcaseId")
    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("value"))
    .FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get list of the attribute "value" with in the element "property" whose other attribute "name" should note be null

You can try below code:

```
var testcaseid1 = xdoc.Root.Descendants("property").Where(s => s.Attribute("name") != null).Select(s => s.Attribute("value").Value).ToList();
```

Or you can select the value of first occurrence using below code:

```
string testcaseid = xdoc.Root.Descendants("property").Where(s => s.Attribute("name") != null).Select(s => s.Attribute("value").Value).First();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the value attribute you can use the following:

```
var foo = (from n in xml.Descendants("property")
           where n.Attribute("name").Value == "TestcaseId"
           select n.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Gives: `70592`

Comment: Seriously?! `xml.Descendants().Elements("property")`?!

Comment: Relax? The query is fine. I've cleaned it up for you

Comment: The fact that it returns correct results does not mean it's fine. `Descendants().Elements("property")` is highly inefficient...

Comment: But it still uses `Descendants()`, which will check whole XML tree (including all `<category>` tags in given XML example) before finding `<property>` elements. Still can be done better...

Comment: We are likely only seeing a small portion of the OP's XML structure. It's likely that the `test-case` node is a child of some other node or more than one other node, perhaps `test-cases`. In which case, your code fails (with an exception) and this succeeds. I think it's a matter of getting a complete sample of the XML before we can claim a *right* or *wrong* answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36444/discussion-between-marcinjuraszek-and-dgibbs)